# How to unit test method using Stream.generate?

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, java-8, java-stream, blockingqueue

I've been spending the last couple of hours trying to figure out what's the best way to test this piece of code.

```
void consume() {
  executorService.execute(() -> Stream.generate(this::takeFromQueue)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .forEach(messageSender::send));
}

private Optional<Message> takeFromQueue() {
  try {
     return Optional.ofNullable(queue.take());
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     log.error("Queue consumer interrupted.");
     return Optional.empty();
  }
```

}

The idea of the code is to provide a consumer of a BlockingQueue that runs in a separate thread until the application ends. 
In this situation I cannot mock the executorService because the test would hang waiting for the thread to finish an infinite stream. If I leave the execution run in a separate thread, the test won't be deterministic and I would need to rely on a Thread.sleep to give it time to at least consume a message from the queue. 
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no reason to test `Stream.generate`, that method is already well tested. You should make test cases for `takeFromQueue()` and for `send()`, not for the trivial stream chain. By the way, `take()` never returns `null`, hence, there is no reason to use `ofNullable`. Since you’re effectively looping forever and ignoring interruption, just calling `take()` again, there is no need to deal with `Optional` at all. Looping inside `takeFromQueue` until `take()` succeeds would have the same effect.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the title is not the right one. I don't want to test Stream.generate, I want to test the code that uses it. I don't get the part where I should test `takeFromQueue()`, to me that's the less important part, specially if I remove the `Optional` and it only loops forever. What I think I should be testing is that every object taken from the queue is sent to `messageSender`. And that's where I don't know how to do it basically because in a single threaded scenario, the test would hang while taking from the queue and in a multithreaded one it would depend on how fast the system is.

Comment: Testing “that every object taken from the queue is sent to `messageSender`” means testing that the method `consume()` does its job. So it’s not related to the Stream API at all. But testing a method that contains an infinite loop has its obstacles…

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change method consume() to consume(Stream)
and call it in the test with a Stream of fixed size.

In your real code than call it with consume(Stream.generate(this::takeFromQueue))